# Puzzle hint verbage unclear - unsure how to decode/decrypt message

Tags: encryption, decode, puzzle

I'm working on solving a puzzle and I ran into a phrase (see in bold below) that seems to be more puzzling than the puzzle itself so far. Here's what the puzzle says:

The password is [64bit hex code here]. Use it to decode the message below.
[Hex string goes here].
(HINT: Text is in hex; **Cross the OR with the pass.**)

Really puzzled as to what "Cross the OR with the pass." means in English as far decoding is concerned. 
I'm happy to share actual hex string and password in direct message if desired.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just a word joke, they probably  mean an X with "cross". So you have to XOR it. They assumed you knew about XOR...

Comment: Thanks, Maarten. Yes, that was one of my ways of thinking about the "cross" and I did, in fact, XOR the hex string with the hex password, but only gibberish came out on the end. So I was thinking maybe I'm not quite getting the "cross the OR with the pass"?

Comment: Well, it almost certainly points to XOR, but without the rest of the puzzle, that's all I can say.

Comment: Thanks, Maarten. The password is [00 63 56 67 CD 0F EC DC] and the hex string to XOR it with is  [695f431358575252632d4467651a2b3642105a5643535a1733254335322c36271059450915770f7602727671737477027605020a741816712c3610233d37362210534456515f421b632055252a27216344-------deleteAllHyfensHere-----------585313535f58562f6440273630332c4254161b7d7f786379640175652a3763445853135b435b552636197c651306050e0d700d657378750c7962067a]

Comment: I put spaces in between password and hyphens inside the string, but please, delete those

Comment: I would appreciate it you could take a look. I just ran it with cyberchef https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/ but all comes out as gibberish in any encoding in the output after the XOR with password....

Comment: I don't see it directly either, so I guess you'll have to puzzle some more. Use different orders of the key, try and shift bits, and use both OR and XOR for instance. Or give up and do something useful, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Maarten, will do!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, conversely, with XOR by using the short HEX as input and long HEX string as key and it revealed the hidden message! Thanks all, and Maarten, for your comments!

Comment: Instead u could give him an upvote for appreciation